# OpenVMS Alpha boot sector restoration

Tags: alpha, boot, openvms

recently I got my hands on Alpha Station computer with OpenVMS operating system (Files-11 filesystem). This computer is from the year 1994.
In an attempt to backup hard drive data, hard disc was connected to an x86 computer with Windows 7 OS.

But it seems that the Windows OS corrupted or rewrote the boot sector of OpenVMS, because now Alpha Station won't boot correctly. 
I managed to get into the operator console (by booting from OpenVMS Alpha v.7.0 installation CD), and now I'm a little bit lost.

I made some attempts with WriteBoot utility (http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/343), but I'm not sure how to correctly use it, as I'm unable to find some complete manual for this. When I follow the instructions, I make it to the point, when this utility wants a parameter called "expression" from me. But I don't know what this could be, help doesn't provide any usefull information and I really do not want to do a "try and see" approach (this alpha station is very important, there has to be no more damage).

Does anyone have any experience with restoring Open VMS OS boot block? I would really appreciate any help or direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why you get the "expression" prompt. It would have been better if you captured the used commands, output and posted them here. I suspect Windows wrote a so-called harmless signature on the disk, which corrupted the boot block.

Anyway, Stromasys has a detailed description [detailed description](https://stromasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KBP/How+to+repair+VMS+boot+block) on how to repair a boot block, maybe that helps.

Comment: This answer actually solved my issue. The Stromasys knowledge-base is great, pity I wasn't able to found it myself. In other sources the boot record restoration process wasn't fully described and I didn't mounted the disk (I'm really OpenVMS rookie). It seems that made the difference. Thank you very much.

Comment: Michael, that's the total nonsense reply. You are out of your league here, and out of line. The base topic is well document and perfectly describes the problem. The answer is great also. I don't understand why anybody who knows anything about OpenVMS would give it a 'minus 1' (which may or might not have been you).

Comment: @Hein : From the SO [how to answer guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) : _**Provide context for links** : Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link**, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: @Hein : It gets a -1 mostly for the fact it only provides a link to an outside source but does not capture any of the context in the answer. If that link ever breaks(and it happens on SO) then the answer no longer stands alone by itself. The first sentence is an actual request for more information from the user (which would have been better served as a comment). If the answer is cleaned up and more in line with SO guidelines, I am more than happy to reverse the downvote.

Comment: As it stands this answer doesn't actually answer the question, the link that is directed to does. This is the basis for my original comment.